# Select For Update statement in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to select fields in a record of a table and update just one of these fields. How can I do?

I try this:

```
SELECT v.idvideo, v.title 
FROM video v  WHERE v.schedulingflag IS FALSE AND v.errorflag IS FALSE 
ORDER BY v.idvideo  LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE ;

UPDATE video  SET schedulingflag = true;
```

But in this way it sets field "schedulingflag" true in all record!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `SELECT FOR UPDATE` syntax tells PG that you're going to be updating those records and locks them against concurrent access.  However you still need to issue the appropriate `UPDATE` call to change the particular records you've locked.

In this case, just use the same `WHERE` clause in your `UPDATE`, e.g:

```
UPDATE video  SET schedulingflag = true 
WHERE schedulingflag IS FALSE AND errorflag IS FALSE;
```

Comment: Hi, i want to lock the table, can you see my previous question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707002/lock-table-in-postgresql#comment20571089_14707002

Comment: Note, that he's using a LIMIT 1 for the FOR UPDATE, this generally means that his where clause may return more than 1 record.  Now, since I don't have his DDL for the table, he should use whatever his primary key is to do the update, if its idvideo, then he should use UPDATE video SET scheduleflag=true WHERE idvideo=?. The reason being is that even if he uses the same query (ORDER BY/LIMIT), he could STILL update a different record (a new id could be inserted before it)